# Why is symfony2 not calling my event listeners?

Tags: php, symfony

I have a program with two bundles. One of them (CommonBundle) dispatches an event "common.add_channel", while a service on the other one (FetcherBundle) was supposed to be listening to it. On the profiler, I can see the event common.add_channel in the "Not Called Listeners" section. I don't get why symfony is not registering my listener.

This is my action, inside `CommonBundle\Controller\ChannelController::createAction`:

```
$dispatcher = new EventDispatcher();
$event = new AddChannelEvent($entity);        
$dispatcher->dispatch("common.add_channel", $event);
```

This is my `AddChannelEvent`:

```
<?php

namespace Naroga\Reader\CommonBundle\Event;

use Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\Event;
use Naroga\Reader\CommonBundle\Entity\Channel;

class AddChannelEvent extends Event {

    protected $_channel;

    public function __construct(Channel $channel) {
        $this->_channel = $channel;
    }

    public function getChannel() {
        return $this->_channel;
    }

}
```

This was supposed to be my listener (FetcherService.php):

```
<?php

namespace Naroga\Reader\FetcherBundle\Service;

class FetcherService {

    public function onAddChannel(AddChannelEvent $event) {
        die("It's here!");      
    }
}
```

And here's where I register my listener (services.yml):

```
kernel.listener.add_channel:
    class: Naroga\Reader\FetcherBundle\Service\FetcherService
    tags:
        - { name: kernel.event_listener, event: common.add_channel, method: onAddChannel }
```

What am I doing wrong? Why isn't symfony calling the event listener when I dispatch common.add_channel?

Comment: Standard symfony question: have you cleared the cache after adding listener in services.yml ?

Comment: Yes. Not that it needs, any changes to services.yml are recompiled to the cache if you are using the app_dev.php at each pagehit. I have cleared it many times, though.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The new event dispatcher doesn't know anything about the listeners set on another dispatcher.

In your controller, you need to access the `event_dispatcher` service. A Compiler Pass of the Framework Bundle attached all listeners to this dispatcher. To get the service, use the `Controller#get()` shortcut:

```php
// ...
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;

class ChannelController extends Controller
{
    public function createAction()
    {
        $dispatcher = $this->get('event_dispatcher');
        // ...
    }
}
```